# In PostgreSQL how do you join two tables select separate information

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Having trouble with joins.

I have a table called `subjects`

```
subno   subname
30006   Math
31445   Science
31567   Business
```

I also have a another table called `enrollment`

```
subno sno   
30009 980008
4134  988880
```

etc..

how to list subject numbers and subject names for student 9800007 ?

Comment: SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/dcd01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 select * 
 from subjects s 
   left join enrollment e on s.subno = e.subno  
 where sno=9800007
```

Comment: try using inner join or simply join

Comment: I suspect you meant to have the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` order reversed. Try in the SQLFiddle linked in the comments.

Comment: hope this isnt being painful but also in the subjects table is a quota column for the various subjects such as 300 for math,400 for science.

how do List subject number and name which quota is less than the average quota of subjects.

do i have to count the number of students in enrollment table and compare?

Comment: @user2314197 Please post that as a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227473/in-postgresql-how-do-you-join-two-tables-whilst-operating-another-function-such

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return zero rows for students without an enrolment, use a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, eg:

```
SELECT e.sno, s.subno, s.subname
FROM enrollment e LEFT OUTER JOIN subjects s ON s.subno = e.subno
WHERE e.sno=988880;
```

To return no rows for students without enrolments, use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT e.sno, s.subno, s.subname
FROM enrollment e INNER JOIN subjects s ON s.subno = e.subno
WHERE e.sno=988880;
```

Note that join order is important for outer joins (`RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN` and `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` - the `OUTER` keyword is optional) but not for `INNER JOIN`. For that reason, @swetha's answer has a problem: the join order is reversed if you're looking for information about a student.

See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/dcd01/2)