# In PostgreSQL how do you join two tables whilst operating another function such as count

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Following on from [my prior question about joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206841/in-postgresql-how-do-you-join-two-tables-select-separate-information) I'm now having trouble with joins and comparing using count function.

I have a table called subjects

```
subno   subname   quota
30006   Math      300    
31445   Science   400 
31567   Business  250
```

I also have a another table called enrollment

```
subno sno   
30009 980008
4134  988880
31567 900890
```

etc. (Converted to SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/dcd01 -- Craig)

How do i List subject number and name which quota is less than the average quota of subjects. This means i need to count the number of students in one table and compare with the other table correct?

Comment: Have you tried any queries?

Comment: Why is this tagged for both mysql and postgres?

Comment: You copied and pasted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206841 without even keeping the formatting! Please [**read the FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and make the effort to format your questions. Read the Info tab of [tag:postgresql] for guidance on asking better questions. Remember it takes us longer to answer (and we're less likely to) if you've made less effort. Always include your expected results, the versions of any relevant software, and wherever possible an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) of your data. Most importantly, **always explain what you have already tried**.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I wonder that do. I presume people do that to try to get more coverage (not everyone who reads [tag:postgresql] or [tag:mysql] reads [tag:sql]) and/or to implicitly suggest "I want this query to work on both databases".

Comment: Why are enrolments relevant? Your question *List subject number and name which quota is less than the average quota of subjects* can be answered by just examining data in the subjects table - the quota is stored there.

Comment: @Bohemian I suspect the requirement here is to find out which subjects still have room in them, by counting how many students are enrolled in each. The top table only lists the maximum size for each subject, not it's individual enrollments.

Comment: @Nisan.H then what is the relevance of the average? This question is a loser - I'm voting to close. And btw, "its" has no apostrophe where you used it :)

Comment: @Bohemian thanks for pointing it out. I'll make sure to triple proof my comments for typos in the future.

Comment: Thank you @CraigRinger for your input and editing, appreciate the effort. I will take into consideration what you have said, however i think my attempts at this question are poor and somewhat novice.

Comment: @Bohemian - the purpose of this question is to compare the number of enrollments with the quota and produce the subject with < quota.

Comment: Why didn't you just say that? Why did you mention "average"? Please keep questions a brief and accurate as possible, and importantly exclude all info not *required* to clarify the question.

Answer (score 2):

After finally determining the question (deduced from comments) to be:

> List all subjects with vacancies

The query you need is:

```
select
    subno,
    subname,
    quota,
    quota - count(sno) as vacancies
from subjects s
left join enrollments e on e.subno = s.subno
group by 1, 2, 3
having quota - count(sno) > 0
```

I also added in a column `vacancies`, which displays the number of vacancies remaining.

Note: You have misspelled "enrolments" (correct spelling has only *one* L) - I recommend you rename your table to the correct spelling to avoid future confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.subno,b.subname 
from
(select subno, count(sno) as cnt from enrollment
group by 1
having count(sno)<(select avg(quota) from subjects)
) as a 

inner join 

(select * from subjects) as b 
on a.subno=b.subno
```

Comment: In the schema created by you on sqlfiddle, there was no column called quota in the subjects table